# Is there any way to merge unbounded arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Recently I got a coding challenge where I was given some arrays like the following:
`[(4, 5.6], (5, 9.1], [-2, -3.5]]`
Here `(` means that the array is unbounded in left side i.e. does not include that number but includes everything else for example, `(4, 5.6]` does not include 4 but everything else between 4 and 5.6 and includes 5.6. I can merge the arrays if I have `[` instead of `(` with the following code. Based on my research, I can not represent such an array in numpy.
So, first thing is how do I represent such an array in my code? Or, is it not an array but represented in a different way?

```
def MergeIntervals(intervals):
    result = []

    intervals.sort()

    i, L = 0, len(intervals)-1

    while i<L:
        if intervals[i+1][0] <=intervals[i][1]:
            intervals[i+1][0] = intervals[i][0]
            intervals[i+1][1] = max(intervals[i][1], intervals[i+1][1])
            intervals[i] = None
        i+=1

    return [interval for interval in intervals if interval]
```

```
intervals = [[4,5.6],[5,9.1],[-2, -3.5]]
MergeIntervals(intervals)
[[-2, -3.5], [4, 9.1]]
```

This is the brute force way I did. I am sure complexity can be improved.
However, I am not sure how to make it operate on an unbounded array like I got in the question. 
I have not yet found any similar question and/or answer here.
Thank you and appreciate any help.

Comment: The only case where it matters is a case like `[[3, 4), (4, 5]]`. Those two intervals cannot be merged. But `[[3, 4), [4, 5]]` and `[[3, 4], (4, 5]]` can be merged into `[[3, 5]]`. I would represent the ranges as an array of tuples, e.g. `[(4, 5.6, 'UB'), (5, 9.1, 'UB'), (-2, -3.5, 'BB')]` where `'UB'` means unbounded on the left, bounded on the right. `'BB'` means bounded on the left, bounded on the right.

Comment: those are not arrays but intervals (or ranges, but not in the python sense). Furthermore they are not called unbounded, but open.

Comment: There are no mathematical intervals in Python/Numpy. You may use, for example, `python-intervals` (https://pypi.org/project/python-intervals/) or create your own data type.

Answer (score 1):

Represent every interval as a list of tuples as so (begin point, is begin point included, end point, is end point included).

Assume that the array is sorted and all partial intervals are legal.
Example for legal intervals:
i1 = [(1,True,1.5,False), (3,False,3.5,False), (3.5,False,5,True)]
i2 = [(0.02, False,1,False), (3,True,4,False),(5,False,7,True)]

BTW I liked that question

```py
def mergeTupelToInterval(tup,inter):
    if tup[2]<inter[0][0]:
        return [tup]+inter
    if tup[2]==inter[0][0] and tup[3] == False and inter[0][1]==False:
        return [tup] + inter
    if tup[0]>inter[-1][2]:
        return inter+[tup]
    if tup[0]==inter[-1][2] and (not tup[1]) and (not inter[-1][3]):
        return inter+[tup]

    relevant = []
    for i in range(len(inter)):
        if inter[i][0]<=tup[0]<inter[i][2]:
            relevant.append(i)
            continue
        if tup[0]==inter[i][2] and (tup[1]or inter[i][3]):
            relevant.append(i)
            continue
        if inter[i][0]<tup[2]<=inter[i][2]:
            relevant.append(i)
            continue
        if tup[2]==inter[i][0] and (tup[3] or inter[i][1]):
            relevant.append(i)

    min = tup
    max = tup
    min_index = 0
    if len(relevant)>1:
        relevant.reverse()
    for i in relevant:
        if inter[i][0]<=tup[0]:
            min = inter[i]
            min_index = i
        if inter[i][2]>=tup[2]:
            max = inter[i]
        inter.pop(i)
    bool1 = min[1]
    if min[0]==tup[0]:
        bool1 = (min[1] or tup[1])
    bool2 = max[3]
    if max[2]==tup[2]:
        bool2 = (max[3] or tup[3])
    new_tup = (min[0],bool1,max[2],bool2)
    inter.insert(min_index,new_tup)


def merge_intervals(i1, i2):
    merged = i1.copy()
    for i in i2:
        mergeTupelToInterval(i,merged)
    return merged


i1 = [(1,True,1.5,False), (3,False,3.5,False), (3.5,False,5,True)]
i2 = [(0.02, False,1,False), (3,True,4,False),(5,False,7,True)]
print(merge_intervals(i1, i2))
```

output is

> [(0.02, False, 1.5, False), (3, True, 7, True)]

Comment: Thanks! It is more complicated than I first anticipated.